# Calculate the number of occurrences of words in a column and find the second, third most common

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula that finds the frequent occurring text and works well.

=INDEX(Rng,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(Rng,Rng)),COUNTIF(Rng,Rng),0))

How can I tweak to find the second highest, third highest?

Comment: tried 'LARGE(Rng,2)` & 'LARGE(Rng,3)` 
?

Comment: @p._phidot_ post it as your answer and I for one will vote.

Comment: @SolarMike let's vote on player0 ans.. ( :

Comment: @p._phidot_ it doesn't work, my range is entire text values and words like Apples, Oranges etc.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "second highest, third highest" in the "Apples and Oranges" context. Perhaps you are trying to count the number of occurrences?

Comment: Lacks a clear example which would make it easier to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd:

```
=LARGE(A2:A; 2)
```

3rd:

```
=LARGE(A2:A; 3)
```

---

### update 1:

use query:

```
=QUERY(A:A, 
 "select A,count(A) where A is not null group by A label count(A)''")
```

[image]

to get only 2nd or 3rd you can use index like:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(A:A, 
 "select A,count(A) where A is not null group by A label count(A)''"), 2)
```

---

### update 2:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({'Data Entry Errors'!I:I}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc limit 3 label count(Col1)''"),,1)
```

Comment: it doesn't work, my range is entire text values and words like Apples, Oranges etc.

Comment: Real Apologies, done now, Sincere Apologies

Comment: Link to the sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jA_HbajHBxUJOdW45ZoJcgsp8vWgwSQtvoUZltKQu7g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @doubleunary I just copypasted first 300 rows

Comment: @player0 OK, update 2 would probably work provided that the range reference is fixed and an `offset` clause is added. The two formulas in update 1 remain incorrect, consider removing them. Also consider removing the unnecessary { array expression }, and adding a `headers` parameter to ensure the first data row get interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Sheets, to get the number of occurrences of each word in the column `A2:A`, use this:

`=query(A2:A, "select A, count(A) where A is not null group by A order by count(A) desc label count(A) '' ", 0)`

To get just the second and third result and the number of their occurrences, use this:

`=query(A2:A, "select A, count(A) where A is not null group by A order by count(A) desc limit 2 offset 1 label count(A) '' ", 0)`

To get just the names that are the second and third by the number of their occurrences, use this:

`=query( query(A2:A, "select A, count(A) where A is not null group by A order by count(A) desc limit 2 offset 1 label count(A) '' ", 0), "select Col1", 0 )`

Answer (score 0):

For **Excel 365**

Say we have data in column **A** from **A2** through **A66** like:

```
20
11
27
18
3
31
2
30
8
1
18
32
3
5
4
6
4
1
22
11
2
46
33
34
25
53
37
9
20
2
12
4
5
4
23
39
19
4
28
22
5
16
24
7
6
10
13
31
56
23
1
16
27
39
1
6
11
6
20
11
24
12
9
29
12
```

and we want a frequency table listing the most frequent value, the second most frequent value, the third, etc.

The simplest approach is to construct a Pivot Table, but if you need a formula approach, then in **B2** enter:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A66)
```

in **C2** enter:

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A$66,B2)
```

We now sort cols **B:C** by **C**.  In **D2** enter:

```
=SORTBY(B2:C35,C2:C35,-1)
```

:
[image]